# rake command looks for Rakefile up the directory chain?

Tags: ruby

I am using Rails3 and accidentally I ran rake command from within lib directory. rake command successfully ran. I think rake command looks for Rakefile all the up the chain. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  According to http://docs.rubyrake.org/user_guide/chapter02.html you can avoid that by:

```
rake -N
```